# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python

This is a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game. When the game is completed, the function `gameover()` is called and a label (congratulatory message i.e playername wins!) has to be displayed on another window. I am trying to achieve this by using a format operator, set() and get() functions.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\ZPrograms\XOXO.py", line 59, in 
>       playerX=winplayX.set()
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

How do I solve this?

Code:

```
playerX = StringVar()
playerY = StringVar()
winplayX = StringVar()
winplayY = StringVar()

winplayX= playerX.get()
winplayY= playerY.get()

playerX=winplayX.set()
playerY=winplayY.set()

u=Frame(root)
u.grid(row=1)

playerX_name = Label( u, text="Player X:", font='Times 25 bold', bg='white', fg='black', height=1, width=10)
playerX_name.grid(row=1, column=2)

playerX_name=Entry(u,textvariable=playerX,font="Times 25")
playerX_name.grid(row=1, column=3)

v=Frame(root)
v.grid(row=2)

playerO_name = Label( v, text="Player O:", font='Times 25 bold', bg='white', fg='black', height=1, width=10)
playerO_name.grid(row=2, column=0)

playerO_name = Entry(v,textvariable=playerY,font="Times 25")
playerO_name.grid(row=2, column=3)

def gameover(winflag):
    win= Toplevel()
    win.title("Game Over")
    win.geometry("260x260+614+339")
    global winplayX
    global winplayY

    if  winflag==1:
            wLabel1=Label(win, text="%s Wins!"%winplayX,font='Times 20 bold').place(x=80, y=80)
    elif winflag==2:
            wLabel2=Label(win, text="%s Wins!"%winplayY,font='Times 20 bold').place(x=80, y=80)
    elif winflag==3:
            wLabel3=Label(win, text="It is a tie",font='Times 20 bold').place(x=80, y=80)
```

Comment: Could you add the full traceback and not only the last line? There are useful infomation to identify where the error happens exactly.

Comment: `playerX.get()` returns a `str`, which you subsequently try to use as a `StringVar` in `playerX = winplayX.set()`. It's not clear what you think that bit of circular code should do.

Comment: playerX=winplayX.set() i think here is the problem becuase here strring is paased

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do, is just have the player names be outputted. You can just change this code:

```
playerX = StringVar()
playerY = StringVar()
winplayX = StringVar()
winplayY = StringVar()

winplayX= playerX.get()
winplayY= playerY.get()

playerX=winplayX.set()
playerY=winplayY.set()
```

to this:

```
winplayX = StringVar()
winplayY = StringVar()

winplayX.set("Player1")
winplayY.set("Player2")
```

Comment: I did not have those two lines at first (no errors) and when the game was completed, the congratulatory message did not include the player's name (just "wins!" instead of "playername wins!"). I am new to Python, I looked up the last program my teacher taught in the class, it had set() along with get(), so I thought I should use set() too.

Comment: @MatthewHolliday See my updated answer and let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: No, that's not what I wanted (Thanks for your help though). There are two textboxes (`playerX_name` and `playerY_name`) for player names. These names are assigned to `playerX` and `playerY` (Both are`StringVar`).  Using `get()` I pass/assign them to `winplayX` and  `winplayY`.

In function `gameover()` 'winflag' is passed from another function. The value of 'winflag' is used in if condition statements to display the congratulatory label.
If Alex and Bob are the players and Alex won, the label should be "Alex wins!" currently I get "wins!" (I have not included the set() lines).

Comment: You are creating `playerX` right before you try to assign its value to `winplayX`, there is no way it can have a value already. There is no relationship between `playerX_name` and `playerX` apart from their names being similar.